# Boost IPC Message_Queue try_receive throws interprocess_exception::library_error

Tags: c++, exception, boost, c++11, boost-interprocess

I am making interprocess communication between two of my processes with boost::interprocess::message_queue.

This is the first time I'm using it so this exception isn't clear to me because I cannot find any documentation on it.

I have my classes setup as following:

```
struct Pos{float X,Y,Z;};
struct Quat{float W,X,Y,Z;};
typedef unsigned char Byte;
struct NPCDataFoot
{
    //some Pos and Quat variables here too
    unsigned short AnimationIndex;
    void Apply(NPCDataFoot &data){AnimationIndex=data.AnimationIndex;}
    NPCDataFoot(){AnimationIndex=0;}
};
struct NPCDataVehicle
{
    //many many more
    unsigned short lrAnalog;
    void Apply(NPCDataVehicle &data){lrAnalog=data.lrAnalog;}
    NPCDataVehicle(){lrAnalog = 0;}
};
enum TransmissionDataType{
    TDT_NewNPC,//many more...
};
const unsigned short QueueMaxSize = 256;
struct ExchangeData
{
    unsigned short  CommandType;
    unsigned short  NPCPlayerID;
    Byte            State;
    NPCDataFoot     OnFootData;
    NPCDataVehicle  InCarData;
    float MoveSpeed;
    Pos MoveToPos;
    //206
    ExchangeData(unsigned short CommandType = 0, unsigned short NPCPlayerid = 0xFFFF)
        : CommandType(CommandType), NPCPlayerID(NPCPlayerid)
    {}
    ExchangeData(unsigned short CommandType, unsigned short NPCPlayerid, NPCDataFoot& foot_data, NPCDataVehicle& car_data)
        : CommandType(CommandType), NPCPlayerID(NPCPlayerid), OnFootData(foot_data), InCarData(car_data)
    {}
};
```

both my programs are set to compile with the /zp1 flag (Align structures/classes to 1-byte alignment).

now whenever I reach this code:

```
ServerMsgQueue * message_queue = NULL;
PLUGIN_EXPORT void PLUGIN_CALL
    ProcessTick()
{
    static bool init = false;
    static ExchangeData DataTransmision;
    if(!init)
    {
        try
        {
            ServerMsgQueue = new message_queue(open_or_create              
                    ,string_format("REMOTESHAREDMEMORYBTWNPRCS%04x",GetServerVarAsInt("port")).c_str()
                    ,1024 * QueueMaxSize,sizeof(ExchangeData)); 
        }
        catch(interprocess_exception &ex)
        {
            std::cout << ex.what() << ":" << __FILE__ << ":" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        }
        init = true;
    }
    static unsigned int unused;
    if(ServerMsgQueue)
    {
        try
        {
            if(ServerMsgQueue->try_receive(&DataTransmision,sizeof(ExchangeData),unused,unused))
            {
                switch(DataTransmision.CommandType)
                {//some cases
                default:{std::cout << "UNKNOWN RECEIVED DATA!!!" << std::endl;break;}
                }
            }
        }
        catch(interprocess_exception &ex)
        {
            //this happens always
            std::cout << ex.what() << ":" << __FILE__ << ":" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The application keeps issuing "boost::interprocess_exception::library_error" in the block where `try_receive` is being used.

What am I doing wrong in this case? I'm sure the data send is the same size because 1) i use the same header and 2) I compile with the same options.

I have confirmed that the variable sizes are the same with the following code in both programs:

```
MessageBox(NULL,string_format(
"Pos(%d):Quat(%d):NPCDataFoot(%d):NPCDataVehicle(‌​%d):ExchangeData(%d)",
sizeof(Pos),sizeof(Quat),sizeof(NPCDataFoot),sizeof(NPCData‌Vehicle),sizeof(ExchangeData)).c_str()
,"Reported sizes Client",0);
```

---

Edit: I seem have "solved" it.. magicly;

It seems that this code was the error:

```
static unsigned int unused;
if(ServerMsgQueue->try_receive(&DataTransmision,sizeof(ExchangeData),unused,unused))
```

changed it to

```
unsigned int Priority;
size_t sizexxx;
if(ServerMsgQueue->try_receive(&DataTransmision,sizeof(ExchangeData),sizexxx,Priority))
```

Can someone explain why this works and the other code not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the source code for [`message_queue::do_receive`](https://gitorious.org/boost/interprocess/source/c820bd26e2f6fdba1c4c3b7a749fa1eb8ceed61f:include/boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp#L590) (called from `message_queue::try_receive`); `do_receive` first writes the message size to the "out" parameter `recvd_size` (a reference to `unused` in your code), then writes the priority to the "out" parameter `priority` (*also* a reference to `unused` in your code -- thus effectively overwriting `recvd_size` with the `priority` value).  Immediately below, the call to `memcpy` uses the now incorrect `recvd_size`, leading to the behaviour you observed (incomplete copy or buffer overrun, depending on `priority`).

Arguably, the author of the library should have used the original `top_msg->len` (instead of the "out" parameter `recvd_size`) for the `memcpy` bytecount.  However, in order to avoid these kinds of surprises, always use distinct variables for "out" parameters (call them `unused1` and `unused2` if you so desire).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by your use of `/zp1`. Your program and the libraries to which it links will think that structures have different sizes and/or member locations. Don't do that.

Comment: the sizes seem to be the same: http://imgur.com/Ww5I7YW (used the following code: `MessageBox(NULL,string_format("Pos(%d):Quat(%d):NPCDataFoot(%d):NPCDataVehicle(%d):ExchangeData(%d)",sizeof(Pos),sizeof(Quat),sizeof(NPCDataFoot),sizeof(NPCDataVehicle),sizeof(ExchangeData)).c_str(),"Reported sizes Client",0);`)